# Windows Batch - read result from cmd command and save to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to read the hostname of my device and generate a file with such name. However, I am new in Windows Batch, I don't even understand how to use of those variable, read file......

Here is what I want to do:

```
CD C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\
CMD.EXE hostname -> to a HostName variable e.g. called abc ::I hope it will save my computer name to a variable string
echo It success to function >> C:\%abc%.txt :: I hope it can generate a file with the sting in variable
PAUSE
```

I have thought that if it is not function with cmd command, so I tried the alternative method:

```
CD C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\
CMD.EXE hostname >> C:\HostName.tmp
-AND THEN READ BACK the C:\HostName.tmp Here
-And then save to a variable again e.g. 
echo It success to function >> C:\HostName_variable.txt ::It generate a file with the sting in variable
PAUSE
```

It seems not successful =[.

Added:
I would like to create a file with the name of hostname. e.g. if my hostname is "abc", it will output a file as "abc.csv" something like this.

Comment: `echo %computername%>newfile.txt`. Type `set` to see a list of variables.

Comment: May be I clarify something, I don't even know how to save the cmd result to a variable (CMD.EXE hostname >> HostName_variable)<----This is what I prefered to save the cmd result

Comment: I showed you above. `echo %computername%>%computername%.csv`. One line, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it two ways:

Environment variables are a few pre-configured variables containing general system state, and one of them is COMPUTERNAME, which you can send straight to a file like:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME% > hostname_file.txt
```

Or you can store it in another variable, first, then echo the content of that variable to a file:

```
set myHostName=%HOSTNAME%
echo %myHostName% > hostname_file.txt
```

The other way is running the hostname.exe program which prints the current computer name, and redirect the output to a file:

```
hostname > hostname_file.txt
```

It's harder to run hostname.exe and store the result in a variable, you need to abuse a for loop to do that:

```
for /f %f in ('hostname') do set myHostName=%f
echo %myHostName% > hostname_file.txt
```

NB. What you are doing isn't quite how you describe it - a file isn't the same thing as a variable:

You write:

```
CD C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\
CMD.EXE hostname >> HostName_variable ::It will save my computer name to a variable string
echo It success to function >> C:\HostName_variable.txt ::It generate a file with the string in variable
PAUSE
```

cmd.exe is unnecessary because you're already in a command prompt when you run it, you don't need another one to run. You don't need to change to c:\windows\system32 first, because Windows always looks there for programs to run. `>>` is adding to the end of a file if it exists, it won't always create a new file, `>` will always create a new file and if one already exists, will overwrite it. Once it has sent the output to a file, it's not in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your details comment. However, I would like to create a file with the name of hostname.
e.g. if my hostname is "abc", it will output a file as "abc.csv" something like this.
Any comment for it?

Comment: Try `echo 1,2,3 > "%COMPUTERNAME%.csv"`

Comment: Thanks =]
Wanna to know where to check the commands like "%COMPUTERNAME%"

Comment: `SET` at the command prompt will print all the environment variables, there's only a few. `SET /?` will show the help for them, and yes there are special ones for %DATE%, %TIME% and %RANDOM% which don't show in the list but you can still use them.